# Weblogic JMS infinite loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jms, weblogic

Good morning to everyone.

I have a J2EE EJB application that is connected to a Weblogic JMS Queue.
In my Development and testing Weblogic Environment there is no problem, but in the productive environment , when a TransactionRollbackException occurs, the JMS message is returned to the Queue and is read again and again.
On the other environments, when this exception occurs, the message is simply rejected and not processed.

Anyone know if this behavior is configurable in Weblogic? I need to configure Weblogic for reject the message if an error occurred.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a dirty read. This is a big problem because the server can potentially fall if there are many messages that fail. I don't know if there is a setting in the WebLogic server for the limit of times the a message is to be reread. I would suggest that you put a property in the message's properties like `rereadCount` and on every bad read you increase that count. If the count reaches 3 let's say you log a message an mark the message as read. This should fix your problem.